# Second item clicked does not function properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I created a jquery code which for some reason works the first time but the second item clicked staggers away with the rest while the first item clicked remains visible. It is pretty weird. Actually the way I set the variables and used them should mean that only the item clicked stays while the others stagger away.

Any idea what is going on?

Here the jsfiddle where you can see the code in action: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HCY5m/33/

my javascript code:

```
  var children = $('.icons').children();
  var icons = new TimelineLite({paused:true});

children.click(function(event) {
      var siblings = $(this).siblings()
      span = $(this).find("span").first()
      content = $(this).find("div")
      h1 = content.find("h2")
      li = content.find("li")
      clicks =  $(this).data('clicks');
      icons.staggerTo(siblings, 1.3, {left:"-150%", ease:Back.easeIn}, 0.1)

  if (clicks) {
     TweenMax.to(span, 1, {opacity:0, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     TweenMax.to(content, 1, {display:"none", delay:1.5, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     TweenMax.to(h1, 1, {opacity:0, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     TweenMax.to(li, 1, {opacity:0, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     setTimeout(function(){ icons.reverse(); }, 500);
  } else {
     TweenMax.to(span, 1, {opacity:0, delay:1.5, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     TweenMax.to(content, 0, {display:"block", delay:1.5, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     TweenMax.to(h1, 1, {opacity:1, delay:1.5, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     TweenMax.to(li, 1, {opacity:1, delay:1.5, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     TweenMax.to(this, 1, {width:"46%", top:"2em", left:"-2%", delay:1.5, ease:Power2.easeInOut})
     icons.play()
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Comment: Your link to `TimelineMax.js` doesn't work. It returns an HTML page.

Comment: @Guffa corrected, linked properly

Comment: The only problem seems to be the stagger effect

Comment: On the first click, the icon is enlarged by this line: 

`TweenMax.to(this, 1, {width:"46%", top:"2em", left:"-2%", delay:1.5, ease:Power2.easeInOut})`

- I think the code that handles the second click (`if(clicks) { ... }`) is missing a line that reverses this animation.

Comment: @mfk because im adding the reversal later via some if statements since it will be slightly different for every icon. The only issue im having is with the stagger. Somehow the click is permanently bound to the first item clicked.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why yet, but it seems to work when you use a separate TimelineLite instance for each icon: http://jsfiddle.net/mfrikoe/HCY5m/53/

Comment: @mfk indeed, why do you think that is? My method should be valid though right?

Comment: I had a look at the sources of TimeLineLite: calling `staggerTo()` repeatedly `add`s another timeline for each call, i.e., the previously added tweens are never cleared. So, you will indeed have to use multiple instances. Calling `clear()` on the timeline should also work, but that would have to be done after the tween finished. I think using multiple instances is the better approach, as this should also handle furious clicking while the animations are running correctly (I think this might be a problem when using a single instance).

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I have been able to cook. Take a look at a [JSFiddle I created here](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/qg137Ls3/) and let me know if anything is unclear. Here is the JavaScript code of the same without changing anything in HTML or CSS:

```
var APP={};
APP.icons=null;
APP.currentActiveIcon=APP.previousActiveIcon= -1;
APP.moveOutTimelines=APP.focusInTimelines=[];
APP.moveOutDuration=.8;
APP.focusInDuration=.6;
APP.moveOutEase=Back.easeIn;
APP.focusInEase=Power2.easeInOut;
APP.init=function(){
    APP.icons=document.querySelectorAll('.icon');
    APP.initFocusInTweens();
    APP.initMoveOutTweens();
    APP.initListeners();
};
APP.initListeners=function(){
    for(var i=0; i<APP.icons.length; i+=1){
        (function(index){
            (window.addEventListener)?APP.icons[i].addEventListener('click',function(event){APP.onIconClicked(event,index);},false):APP.icons[i].attachEvent('onclick',function(event){APP.onIconClicked(event,index);});
        })(i);
    }
};
APP.initFocusInTweens=function(){
    var span,content,header,listItems;
    for(var i=0; i<APP.icons.length; i+=1){
        span=APP.icons[i].querySelector('span');
        content=APP.icons[i].querySelector('div');
        header=content.querySelector('h2');
        listItems=content.querySelectorAll('li');
        APP.focusInTimelines[i]=new TimelineMax({
            paused:true,
            onStartParams:[content],
            onReverseCompleteParams:[content],
            onStart:function(content){TweenMax.set(content,{display:'block'});},
            onReverseComplete:function(content){TweenMax.set(content,{clearProps:'display'});}
        });
        APP.focusInTimelines[i].to(APP.icons[i],APP.focusInDuration,{width:'46%',top:'2em',left:'-2%',ease:APP.focusInEase},0);
        APP.focusInTimelines[i].fromTo(span,APP.focusInDuration,{autoAlpha:1},{autoAlpha:0,ease:APP.focusInEase},APP.focusInDuration*.4);
        APP.focusInTimelines[i].fromTo(header,APP.focusInDuration,{autoAlpha:0},{autoAlpha:1,ease:APP.focusInEase},APP.focusInDuration*.4);
        APP.focusInTimelines[i].staggerFromTo(listItems,APP.focusInDuration,{autoAlpha:0},{autoAlpha:1,ease:APP.focusInEase},APP.focusInDuration*.2,APP.focusInDuration*.4);
    }
};
APP.initMoveOutTweens=function(){
    for(var i=0; i<APP.icons.length; i+=1){
        APP.moveOutTimelines[i]=new TimelineMax({paused:true});
        APP.moveOutTimelines[i].to(APP.icons[i],APP.moveOutDuration,{left:'-30%',ease:APP.moveOutEase});
    }
};
APP.onIconClicked=function(event,index){
    APP.previousActiveIcon=APP.currentActiveIcon;
    APP.currentActiveIcon=index;
    if(APP.currentActiveIcon!==APP.previousActiveIcon){
        APP.toggleFocus(true);
    }else{
        APP.toggleFocus(false);
        APP.currentActiveIcon= -1;
    }
};
APP.toggleFocus=function(toFocus){
    var i;
    if(toFocus){
        if(APP.focusInTimelines[APP.previousActiveIcon]!==undefined)APP.focusInTimelines[APP.previousActiveIcon].reverse();
        APP.focusInTimelines[APP.currentActiveIcon].play();
        for(i=0; i<APP.icons.length; i+=1){
            if(i!==APP.currentActiveIcon)APP.moveOutTimelines[i].play();
        }
    }else{
        APP.focusInTimelines[APP.currentActiveIcon].reverse();
        for(i=0; i<APP.icons.length; i+=1){
            if(i!==APP.currentActiveIcon)APP.moveOutTimelines[i].reverse();
        }
    }
};
APP.init();
```